# How do I set the alternate search path for a.vim?

Tags: vim, vim-plugins

I recently found out about [a.vim](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=31) which I can see can bring a lot of benefit to developing source code in C or C++. Now, for one of my current projects it works just fine out of the box but for the other one, I would need to set two alternate search paths to make it work accordingly and I have not found out how to do it yet, I've tried the following from the vim command prompt: `:let g:alternateSearchPath "../../../include/pathA/"`but this didn't do anything. How do I correctly set the `g:alternateSearchPath` variable?

Answer (score 2):

You can try [vim-projectionist](https://github.com/tpope/vim-projectionist)

This plugin provides more general uses.

---

Add some useful tips for this plugin:

It cannot work like `a.vim` before you do some step below

1. You can add a `.projections.json` for this project and write

```
{
    "src/*.c" : {"alternate":"include/{}.h"},
    "include/*.h" : {"alternate":"src/{}.c"}
}
```

2. If you tired of writing every project a `.projections.json` file, you can set a default behavior in `vimrc`

```
  let g:projectionist_heuristics = {
      \   "*" : {
      \       "*.c": { "alternate": "{}.h" },
      \       "*.h": { "alternate": "{}.c" }
      \   }
      \ }
```

key `*` here is used for choosing which project do you want to use this settings, it means every project will use `.h` file as `.c`'s alternate file.

3. If you group all your cpp projects in a dirctory for example "$HOME/MyCppProjects/...", the following settings may be better

```
  let g:projectionist_heuristics = {
      \   "MyCProjects/" : {
      \       "*.c": { "alternate": "{}.h" },
      \       "*.h": { "alternate": "{}.c" }
      \   },
      \   "MyCppProjects/" : {
      \       "*.cpp": { "alternate": "{}.h" },
      \       "*.h": { "alternate": "{}.cpp" }
      \   },
      \ }
```

or you can set `g:projectionist_heuristics` by different file types(I have not try but I think it may be ok).